# Breeze WebAPI - Multiple actions were found that match the request

Tags: c#, api, breeze

I am using the John Papa Single Page Application source code to create my own App and I am running into some problems when using the Breeze Web API. I have my own breeze controller and as soon as I add a second HttpGET method I get the error "Multiple actions were found that match the request".

It is Weird because in his code he adds multiple GETs and his code works but I think I am missing something.

**Breeze Controller**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web.Http;
using Breeze.WebApi;
using AgencyUpdate.Models;

namespace AgencyUpdate.Controllers
{
    [BreezeController]
    public class BreezeController : ApiController
    {

        readonly EFContextProvider<AgencyDbContext> _ContextProvider =
            new EFContextProvider<AgencyDbContext>();

        public string MetaData()
        {
            return _ContextProvider.Metadata();
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public IQueryable<api_Agency> GetAgency()
        {
            return _ContextProvider.Context.api_Agency;
        }


        [HttpGet]
        public IQueryable<api_AgencyOffice> GetOffice()
        {
            return _ContextProvider.Context.api_AgencyOffice;
        }

    }
}
```

I use this URL to request data:

```
**http://localhost:13762/api/breeze/GetAgency**
```

Also I have found this .CS file for routing but I don't know if I have to make changes to it.

**BreezeWebApiConfig**

```
using System.Web.Http;

[assembly: WebActivator.PreApplicationStartMethod(
    typeof(AgencyUpdate.App_Start.BreezeWebApiConfig), "RegisterBreezePreStart")]
namespace AgencyUpdate.App_Start {
  ///<summary>
  /// Inserts the Breeze Web API controller route at the front of all Web API routes
  ///</summary>
  ///<remarks>
  /// This class is discovered and run during startup; see
  /// http://blogs.msdn.com/b/davidebb/archive/2010/10/11/light-up-your-nupacks-with-startup-code-and-webactivator.aspx
  ///</remarks>
  public static class BreezeWebApiConfig {

    public static void RegisterBreezePreStart() {
      GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
          name: "BreezeApi",
          routeTemplate: "breeze/{controller}/{action}"
      );
    }
  }
}
```

Does anyone know what the problem is?

Answer (score 2):

I feel a bit stupid the URL I need to use is breeze/breeze/MethodName.

John's code doesn't use breeze twice in the URL hence the confusion

Comment: And you don't have to either. It's all in how you setup your routes

Comment: I guess the issue is how the Nuget package sets up the BreezeWebApiConfig file for you. In the Pluralsight videos, John uses the URL (with API) that nick was using.

Here's the code it generates for you automatically:

`public static void RegisterBreezePreStart() {
      GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
          name: "BreezeApi",
          routeTemplate: "breeze/{controller}/{action}"
      );`

Answer (score 1):

Papa's course has the single-page-apps-jumpstart.zip file with project source code by chapters. The right version the BreezeWebApiConfig.cs content is as such:

```
public static class BreezeWebApiConfig {

    public static void RegisterBreezePreStart() {
      GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
          name: "BreezeApi",
          routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}"
      );
    }
  }
}
```

Notice the string **routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}"**